# How to compare two dates that if one date is less than other

Tags: java

I have two dates like

```
Date dateOfEnq = sdf.parse(ea.getDateOfEnquiry());
Date validDate = DateUtil.getAfterMonth(dateOfEnq, range);
```

Now i am doing

```
if (dateOfEnq <= validDate) {
    ount++;
}
```

but it gives me error that

```
The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) java.util.Date, java.util.Date.
```

how can i compare these two dates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.util.Date implements Comparable interface. That means it has compareTo method which you can use to compare 2 dates

```
 int res = date1.compareTo(date2);
```

- res = 0 if date1 is equal to date2;
- res < 0 if date1 is before date2;
- res > 0 if date1 is after date2

Answer (score 3):

`dateOfEnq.before(anotherDate);`  (or) `dateOfEnq.after(anotherDate);` etc., to compate two dates.

Read [javadoc for more information.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Note: It is better to use latest API like [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) when you want to use dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `after` and `before` methods to compare.